# Difference between Variance Inflation Factor (VIF) and kappa in R?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

I am running a regression analyis in r:

```
fit <- lm(Cost ~ Slope + YardDist, data = test)
```

I want to test the two independent variables for multicollinearity. I tested it with `vif()` (from the car package) and `kappa()`.

```
> vif(fit)
   Slope YardDist 
1.000121 1.000121 
> kappa(fit)
[1] 11631.87
```

VIF tells me there is no multicollinearity and kappa tells me there is very high multicollinearity. 
What is the difference between both and which one is 'right'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only have two variables, you can just check the correlation between them.  The [VIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor) is:
$$
\text{VIF}=\frac{1}{\text{tolerance}}=\frac{1}{1-r^2}
$$
On the other hand, kappa, is the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number); that is:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{\text{max(eigenvalue(X'X))}}{\text{min(eigenvalue(X'X))}}}
$$
One thing that is often recommended with kappa is to center your variables first (note that there is difference of opinion about this recommendation).  If your variables are far from 0, the sampling distributions of the $\beta_j$s will be correlated with the sampling distribution of $\beta_0$ (i.e., the intercept).  *I suspect that's what you are seeing here.*

It might help you to read my question here: [Is there a reason to prefer a specific measure of multicollinearity?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48822/)

Comment: What does it mean 'to center the variables'?

Comment: @user1738154, to *center* a variable you subtract the mean of the variable from each value. Thus the mean of the new variable is **0**, but the SD is the same as before.

Comment: Wow, after centering my variables, the kappa value equals almost the VIF value. Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Comment: @user1738154, the upshot is that your SE / 95% CI for the intercept will be inflated / you will have lower power to differentiate your estimated intercept, $\hat\beta_0$, from $0$. This is due to the fact that your $X_j$ values are far from $x_j=0$ & there is some uncertainty about the slopes. However, most people aren't terribly concerned about this. If, OTOH, *you* are, you will need to run another study where your $X_j$s are centered on $x_j=0$.

Comment: well my kappa value is 1.029708. Doesn't that mean there is no multicollinearity? For the regression function itself (which I am mainly interested in) I can use the non-centered variables, can't I?

Comment: @user1738154, there is no multicollinearity *when your variables are centered*. OTOH, the sampling distribution of $\hat\beta_0$ *is* correlated w/ the other $\hat\beta_j$s, so the SE for $\hat\beta_0$ will be inflated (although the SEs for the other $\hat\beta_j$s will not). The question is whether you care if the SE for $\hat\beta_0$ is larger than it might otherwise be; most people will not care. Your estimates & inferences regarding the other $\hat\beta_j$s will be unaffected.

Comment: Just want to clearify. In my case there is no multicollinearity due to the low kappa value? Or is there in general no multicollinerarity when variables are centered? The fact that the SE will be inflated is as far as I currently know not important.

Comment: Unless you have *perfect* multicollinearity, the concern about MCL is that your SEs will be inflated. However, not all SEs will necessarily be inflated w/ MCL, only some may be. The question then is whether you care about those. In your case, only the SE for the intercept will be inflated, which almost no one ever cares about. Re your questions, I would not say "due to", I would say the low kappa *indicates* there is no MCL *when your variables are centered*, but there is MCL *when your variables are not centered* (viz, the SE for your intercept will be inflated).