# OLSR model: high negative correlation between 2 predictors but low vif - which one decides if there is multicollinearity?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, least-squares, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor

[image]

Date, age, mrt and shops are all predictors in a dataset of 414 observations. Pearson's product-moment correlation shows a sizeable negative correlation between mrt and shops (-0.6 so definitely higher than the minimum benchmark of 2/sqrt(n)). Yet the VIF for both is quite low. Does this mean there is multicollinearity or not? And why is the VIF so low if Pearson's r is -0.6?

Ps: I have found a *similar* question here, but there Pearson's r is not negative and that might mean  a difference. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is largely covered elsewhere, e.g., in my answer to [When can we speak of collinearity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100272/7290).  Whether Pearson's $r$ is positive or negative makes no difference.

I have never heard of your "minimum benchmark", and it doesn't make any sense to me.  Consider that if you only had $4$ data, I gather your minimum benchmark would say that a pairwise correlation between variables equal to $r = 1.0$ would be fine (i.e., $2/\sqrt{4} = 1$), whereas if you had $1600$ data, any $r>.05$ would be problematic (i.e., $2/\sqrt{1600} = .05$).  I may be misunderstanding it, but that's nonsensical.  Consider that, unless you have *perfect* multicollinearity, the primary impact is a reduction of power but that can still be overcome with sufficient $N$ (cf., my answer to: [What is the effect of having correlated predictors in a multiple regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86965/7290)).

By (arbitrary) rule of thumb, you have a 'problem with multicollinearity' when you have a ${\rm VIF} \ge 10$.  With respect to pairwise correlations alone, that would imply $|r| \gtrapprox .95$.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me links to other answers and still taking the trouble to answer my question - much appreciated! As regards the "minimum benchmark" it is from Newbold-Carson-Thorne: Statistics for Business and Economics (ISBN 9780273767060), eighth edition, page 84, bottom of the page. "A useful rule to remember is that a relationship exists if |r| >= 2/sqrt(n)"

Comment: @Reader123, Oh, I see.  They're giving a rule of thumb for eyeballing the statistical significance of a correlation.  That doesn't matter.  With respect to potential multicollinearity, it doesn't matter whether the correlation is 'real' in the population or not.  Multicollinearity is about the correlations *in your sample* being 'too high'.

Comment: Thank you, @gung, I completely missed the aspect of one being about the population and the other about the sample only... :-| Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, @Reader123.