# Can we exclude non-significant variables (p>0.05) in ridge regression?

Tags: statistical-significance, python, p-value, ridge-regression

As far as I know, variables with p>0.05 are non-significant for the regression model.

I found similar questions here about p-value like:
[What is the meaning of p values and t values in statistical tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests)

and this one
[Interpreting non-significant regression coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368685/interpreting-non-significant-regression-coefficients)

But those don't answer my main question which is: can I exclude the variables with p>0.05 and run the model again until I get only significant variables?

Comment: Sure you can.  But the result is rarely worth the effort and often is meaningless.  See our higher-voted threads on variable selection and model building.

Comment: In line with whuber, the question whether you can and the question whether it's any good are quite different. ;-)

Comment: I see!  Thanks whuber and Lewian So, although having non-significant variables, a model can be considered acceptable to define a specific case. It's a bit contra intuitive because it will increase the R^2, leadin Is that correct? Perhaps I need to create another question for this.